# Make numbers copied from Excel to Word use minus sign instead of hyphen to avoid wrapping

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, unicode

When you copy a negative number from Excel to Word, a hyphen/minus (Unicode `&#45;`) is used instead of a proper minus sign (Unicode `&#8722;`). This causes text to wrap after the hyphen (you can't force the second column to do what the first one does):

[image: Word or Excel hyphen as minus bug]

I'd like Excel to copy the proper character. Can I fix this for good somehow? Am I condemned to find and replace each time I paste something from Excel?

---

edit: I'm thinking a possible answer could come from changing the default formats in Excel, but it's just a maybe.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to apply [custom formatting](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Create-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE) with the right character for the minus sign.

Follow these steps:

- Select the cells you want to format,
- right-click and select "Format cells..."
- under the "Number" tab, select "Custom"
- enter `0;–0;(0);@` in the custom field
- click "Ok".

A little explanation about the mysterious code: the semicolons are delimiters for each specific criteria: the first is for positive numbers, the second for negative numbers, the third is for zeroes and the last is for text values.

Neat trick: if you want to use any of the default formatting, first apply the formatting in the normal way. Then select custom formatting. Once you select "Custom", the current formatting is displayed and you can simply change the - into a –.

Comment: Now this is nice. It works. You still have to use the regular hyphen in Excel when you enter values and formulas, but the custom number format presents the Unicode minus sign and it absolutely works when you copy from Excel to Word. Good stuff!

Comment: Great. Is there a similar format for negative exponents in scientific notation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can change the default formats in Excel,
but adding a custom format that mimics the default might be one way to achieve it.

You might also try to change the "Regional settings" in the control panel for an even more general approach (affecting all of the OS, if you can make it happen there - I have not tried it).

edit: Note that the latter might have side effects, depending on what software you use - if any of it assumes a minus is always a hyphen, then you might get strange things on screen.

Comment: That's a close finish ;-) I just checked altering the regional settings (under Win7), which is a (far) more elegant solution, but Excel doesn't seem to bother about that. In the options-section of Excel, you can explicitly follow the regional settings for , and . but not for the minus sign. Too bad...

Comment: Close, yes indeed ;-). Sad about that fact though.

Comment: No no! Don't alter regional settings to use a Unicode symbol for minus. Not all software will be able to cope with that. Stick with *agtoever*'s advice and use Excel custom formatting.

Comment: Right, the usual shortcomings of software come into play ;-) - more sad facts.